# Prevent autoloaded classes to be executed in an MVC

Tags: php, class, autoload

What's the proper way to prevent autoloaded classes to be executed in an MVC taking the first item of the exploded query string as the controller class?

In other words, if the first item happens to be a model class for instance, I don't want it to be executed, even though I'd like to keep the convenience of the autoload functionality.

Comment: you can't "execute" a class. You can only execute functions. Are you talking about creating an instance of the class? An example might help. It's not clear what you mean, or why this is giving you a problem. Can you explain the exact situation, and also demonstrate why this creates an issue for you?

Comment: @ADyson I'm sorry for using the wrong jargon.....I don't want anyone be able to execute a class method from the browser.....for instance, www.site.com/model_user/get_user_by_id/id/ shouldn't be executed even though I have autoloaded the model_user class in the index file.

Comment: that doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Why have you got a controller method for that action, if you don't want to allow it to be executed via a URL? Are you trying to build your own routing engine or something? In a normal MVC framework, the methods of model classes are not called directly as a result of the URL, instead you have controller classes whose methods can be called by giving a certain URL. That way you restrict what can be done to what is explicitly in the controller class. Those controller methods then do whatever is necessary with the models and other classes to complete the task

Comment: I understand. Need to get a better understanding of MVC. Thanks a lot!

Comment: perhaps it's a good idea to work with and study an existing MVC framework before trying to implement your own. There are lots of them, and the PHP-based ones are generally open-source.

Comment: Yea...you're right...no need trying to reinvent the wheel :)